# how to fing unfilled days with python fuction and df

Tags: python, pandas, function

i have a pandas df for which I need a function that will return the name and date if these values ​​​​aren't in the df for last 3 days.

For example my df1:

```
| date       | name           |
| ---------- | -------------- |
| 2022-08-05 | Alex           |
| 2022-08-07 | Alex           |
```

i've tried to resolve it with function:

```
def checker (table, name):
    if len(table[table.names == name]) == 3:
        msg = '\n All good'
    else:
        name_list = [*table['name'].unique()]
        msg = '\n No data for:'
        for name in name_list:
            msg += f'\n {name}'
return msg
```

But how can I add date for that missing name in msg? Or maybe it will be possible to optimize my function?

In ouptup I need a message with name and date if there is no datat for that day in my df:

```
2022-08-06 Alex
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with aggregate functions.

First, group the entries by user:

```py
grouped = table.groupby("name")
```

Then count the number of entries and get the last date for each user *(Note: this is not the original requirement)*:

```py
aggreg = grouped.agg({"name": "count", "date": "max"})
```

To get the **missing** date, you will need to replace `"max"` with a custom function:

```py
aggreg = grouped.agg(
    {"name": "count",
     "date": lambda dates: """code to find the missing
             date in the dates Series for a single user"""})
```

You can finally filter those with count less than 3:

```py
res = aggreg[aggreg.name < 3]
```

Your users will be in `res.index` and the dates in `res.date`.

Comment: Thanks, nice point. but i don't have that output as result. got max date instead of missing date

Comment: I misunderstood the requirement, sorry. You should try a custom aggregate function [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html).

Comment: Edited the answer, if you can provide the missing code I can fill it in.